# How do I use the ValueTuple naming feature with anonymous methods?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, anonymous-methods, valuetuple

I would like to use the naming feature of ValueTuple as follows:

```
     IEnumerable<(string, char, int)> valueTuples = new(string, char, int)[]
     {
        ("First", '1', 1),
        ("Second", '2', 2),
        ("Third", '3', 3)
     };

     var projection1 = valueTuples.Select(((string s, char c, int i) tuple) => tuple.i);
```

But it does not compile with an error message that is not very helpful.  However these both compile:

```
     var projection2 = valueTuples.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1);

     var projection3 = valueTuples.Select(((string, char, int) tuple) => tuple.Item1);
```

Trying a more direct approach, this does NOT compile BUT gives an error
message that is more helpful:

```
     var projection4 = Enumerable.Select(
        valueTuples, ((string s, char c, int i) tuple) => tuple.i);
```

Which leads to trying this, which compiles:

```
     var projection5 = Enumerable.Select<(string, char, int), int>(
        valueTuples, ((string s, char c, int i) tuple) => tuple.i);
```

Which finally inspires this, which compiles:

```
     var projection6 = valueTuples.Select<(string, char, int), int>(
        ((string s, char c, int i) tuple) => tuple.i);
```

Is this a general issue with IEnumerable extension methods?
It would appear not because this compiles:

```
     var filtered = valueTuples.Where(((string s, char c, int i) tuple) => tuple.i > 1);
```

Why do I have to resort to projection6 syntax to get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a list of unnamed tuples `(string, char, int)` (note there are no names). For that reason, access using default names `Item1`, `Item2` and so on works fine.

However, what you pass to `Select` lamdba is named tuple type:

```
(string s, char c, int i) tuple) => tuple.i
```

It appears that type inference does not consider named and unnamed tuples (or two named tuples with different names) completely identical and inference fails in certain cases when such "different" types are used. I'm not completely sure why, maybe it's even a bug, or maybe there is something in specification which covers that.

But, with that knowledge we can figure out that the best way to resolve your problem is to use named tuple type right from the start:

```
IEnumerable<(string s, char c, int i)> valueTuples = new[] {
    ("First", '1', 1),
    ("Second", '2', 2),
    ("Third", '3', 3)
};            
var projection1 = valueTuples.Select(tuple => tuple.i);
```

Update: I actually found an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24781) about this in Roslyn repository. It's a confirmed bug indeed, and it has already been resolved even. There are no explanations about nature of this bug. Fix should appear in version 15.7.

Still even with a fix I consider using named tuple from the start is the best way to go. Then you don't need to specify names again and again in every lambda (and those names can even be different, which makes the whole thing even more confusing).

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is not specifically an issue with IEnumerable, Linq, or extension methods, and can be readily reproduced with with simple generic methods alone.

The C# language spec on type inference can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#type-inference

Comment: Yes, thanks. I missed that simple solution - perhaps because my actual IEnumerable is returned from another method.  But I have access to that method and can give the ValueTuple names in the return signature and that works.  I'm starting to like ValueTuples.